# Regular expression as a list item

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a long list of regular expressions that I imported into a list. When I attempt to use a list item in `re.search` I don't get any matches. However, when I enter manually the same expressions into `re.search` I get matches. Any idea what might be causing this issue

Test string `\windows\temp\zzz.rar`

Test regex `(temp|tmp)\\[a-z]+\.rar`

This doesn't work:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    for expr in expressions:
        matchStr = re.search(r'expr', key, re.I)
        if matchStr:
            print 'Match found'
            break
```

This works:

```
for key, value in data.items():
        for expr in expressions:
            matchStr = re.search(r'(temp|tmp)\\[a-z]+\.rar', key, re.I)
            if matchStr:
                print 'Match found'
                break
```

Comment: Maybe expr is not being passed as a literal to re.search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using expressions from the list of expressions, just string `r'expr'`

Use expr directly, without quotes, e.g. `re.search(expr, key, re.I)`:

```
import re

data = {r'\windows\temp\zzz.rar': 'xxx'}
expressions = [r'(temp|tmp)\\[a-z]+\.rar']

for key, value in data.items():
    for expr in expressions:
        matchStr = re.search(expr, key, re.I)
        if matchStr:
            print('Match found')
            break
```

Prints:

```
Match found
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple :)